# Python Character Hash Sha-256

Tags: python

How to I hash a string or integer in python(sha256)? Is there a method in the python documentation. If so what is the link. Thanks

Comment: Literally the first result: https://google.com?q=python+sha256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import hashlib
var = 'password'
hashedWord = hashlib.sha256(var.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
```

You can check hashlib in the python documentation